# Using jQuery Tools Tabs with Ajax and History and trying to link to content in a tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, history

I'm using jQuery Tools Tabs ability to load content onto my page with Ajax.  I've also got a drop down menu that needs to connect in the content when it loads.  Everything about the tabs utility is working correctly.  However, does anyone have an idea of how to go to a particular anchor or div tag when the content loads?  Typically your tabs have buttons that go with their corresponding documents and that's how they load, but could you therotically do something like this:

```
$(function() {
var initab = 0;
var initab2 = 0;
var lhash = window.location.hash;
if (lhash) { 
    lhash.match(/^#(\d+)-(\d+)/);
    initab = RegExp.$1 - 1;
    initab2 = RegExp.$2 - 1;
}

$("ul.tabs").tabs("> .pane",{initialIndex:initab});
$("ul.tabs2").tabs("> .pane2",{initialIndex:initab2});    
$('ul li a').click(function () {location.hash = $(this).attr('href');});
```

});

This activates a different set of tabs and supports history between the 2 tabs to create a reusable url for users to bookmark with.  I'd like to do a similar thing, but rather than a 2nd set of tabs, I'm trying to connect to an anchor or dive tag in the content.  I appreciate any advice.  Thanks